# Keeps using the wrong choice

Tags: python, if-statement

```
    import time
dead = False

ally = input('Ally?: ')
if ally == 'Yes':
    ally = True
else:
    ally = False

User = input('Name?: ')

if not dead and ally:
    print('Sara\'s hand slipped from yours as you came to a fork in the hallways.')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('')
    print('"Quickly! Which road should we take? Right or Left?"')
    pick = input('Which way?!: ')
    if pick == 'Right' or pick == 'right':
        print('')
        print('"Ok, I trust you!"')
        print('')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('She ran towards the right, only to be stopped by a mysterious figure.')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('.')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('.')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('"ɖɨɖ ʏօʊ ȶʀʏ ȶօ ɛֆƈǟքɛ ɦօռɛʏ?~ ȶֆӄ ȶֆӄ~ ȶɦǟȶ աǟֆռ\'ȶ ɨռ ȶɦɛ ƈօռȶʀǟƈȶ"')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('.')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('.')
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print('')
        print('"' + User + '! It\'s the other way! I\'ll take care of this and be right back!"')
        time.sleep(3)
        print('"ʏօʊ ֆօռ օʄ ʄ*** ɨ աօʀӄɛɖ ȶօօ ɦǟʀɖ ʄօʀ ȶɦɨֆ. ʏօʊ ǟʀɛ ɖɛǟɖ ȶօ ʍɛ!"')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('Obeying her orders, you run as fast as your legs could take you.')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('Leaving her behind...')
        time.sleep(3)
        dead = False
        ally = False
    if pick == 'left' or pick == 'Left':
        print('')
        print('"Ok, I trust you!"')
        print('')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('She walked ahead of you, towards the left where the lights flickered.')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('A figure came from the right side as her eyes widened.')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('')
        print('"RUN AND FOLLOW ME"')
        print('')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('You follow her lead into the darkness as you hear a chuckle which'
              ' sends sparks down your spine, running out a door.')
        dead = False
        time.sleep(2)
if not dead and not ally:
    print('You leave the room from before, seeing a fork in the hallway.')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Which direction do you take?')
    pick = input('Which?: ')
    if pick == 'Right' or pick == 'right':
        print('You decide to take the right path, going down your merry way '
              'as you felt...')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('Cold?')
        time.sleep(3)
        print('A mysterious figure had appeared in front of you covered your nose and '
              'mouth with a cloth containing a sweet smelling liquid')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('Before you went to darkness, you heard them whisper faintly in your ear.')
        time.sleep(0.9)
        print('∑ЯЯ◊Я')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('∑ЯЯ◊Я')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('∑ЯЯ◊Я')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('∑ЯЯ◊Я')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('∑ЯЯ◊Я')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('ㄚ◊ㄩῳ∑Я∑и\'₮ㄅㄩㄕㄕ◊ㄅ∑∂₮◊ﾚ∑∆√∑')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('ㄅｻｻｻ... ﾓ∆ﾚﾚ ∆ㄅﾚ∑∑ㄕ ∂∑∆Я ,' + User + 'ㄚ◊ㄩ ῳ∑Я∑и\'₮ ㄅㄩㄕㄕ◊ㄅ∑∂ ₮◊ ς◊㎡∑ ₮ｻⅰㄅ ﾓ∆Я...')
        time.sleep(5)
        dead = True
    if pick == 'left' or 'Left':
        print('You chose the left path, leading to a door.')
        time.sleep(2)
        print('It was that easy?')
        dead = False
if not dead and ally:
    print('You walk out the door, leading into reality once more.')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Where was the girl from before?')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Looking back, you see nothing behind you.')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('So... Was it all a dream??')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Let\'s hope so.')
    time.sleep(4)
    print('END.')
if not dead and not ally:
    print('You walk out the door, leading into reality once more.')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('You had left her behind...')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Looking back, you see nothing behind you.')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('So... Was it all a dream?')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('Let\'s hope so.')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('For both of your sakes...')
    time.sleep(4)
    print('END.')
    time.sleep(4)
```

I don't exactly understand why this isn't working. When I have an Ally and go to the right, it decides to do the option that is done without the ally which confuses me. If I don't have an Ally and take the right again, it does the same nonsense.
It only works when I don't have an ally and go to the left, help, please?

Comment: I think you're going to have to narrow this down and give a better description of the problem. I at least can't tell what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you the time and story, only the game mechanism remains.
I also removed the  `dead = False`  and  `not dead`  since it does nothing (you already are alive). 
This makes the code look something like:

```
dead = False

ally = input("Ally?: ")
if ally == 'Yes':
    ally = True
else:
    ally = False

if ally: # first scene with ally
    pick = input("Which way?: ")
    if pick == 'Right' or pick == 'right':
        ally = False
    if pick == 'Left' or pick == 'left':
        pass

if not ally: # first scene without ally
    pick = input("Which way?: ")
    if pick == 'Right' or pick == 'right':
        pass
    if pick == 'Left' or pick == 'left':
        pass

if ally: # end scene with ally
    print("Option with ally") ## temp statement
    print('End')

if not ally: # end scene without ally
    print("Option without ally") ## temp statement
    print('End')
```

You basically got two parts: an interactive one and an end scene. 
This results in the following options: 
You have an ally and go to right: go to end scene without ally. 
You have an ally and go to left: go to end scene with ally. 
You have no ally and go to right: you're dead, no end scene for death. 
You have no ally and go to left: go to end scene without ally. 

I'm not sure when you say that it doesn't work, what doesn't work, but my guesses are it must be something in the game mechanism. Or else maybe you put a wrong text on the wrong place. 
Anyway, hope this helps.

almost forgot:
on line 94 you have  `if pick == 'Left' or 'left'` , which should be:  `if pick == 'Left' or pick == 'left'` .

Comment: Oh! I think I get it. Let me try it and if it works I'll be sure to thank you!

Comment: Wait, you aren't supposed to die if you go to the right

Comment: Have you tried removing all of the story and sleep commands (keep an backup of course). This should give you an clear idea of what is happening in your code.

Comment: Hmm... I did create a test but I still seemed not to understand what was wrong. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Not really sure what the problem is then. Edited my answer, hope this will make it clear.

Comment: Yeah! I tried this and it works now, thank you very much!